# C# Database Interface Checking SQL Duplicates

Tags: c#, sql, exception, duplicates

Ok, im buiding a stock system for a car dealer which has the abillity to add new cars to the system, Now i need to add a feature if the dealer types in a car REG which is already in the database it would bring up an error message box.

How would i do this?

Heres the code:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

            String carManufacture = textBoxCARManufac.Text.ToUpper();
            String carModel = textBoxCARModel.Text.ToUpper();
            String carColour = textBoxCarBodColo.Text.ToUpper();
            int carMileage = int.Parse(textBoxCArMillea.Text);
            int carYearReg = int.Parse(textBoxCARREGYear.Text);
            String carReg;
            String fuel = textBoxCARFuel.Text.ToUpper();
            int carEng = int.Parse(textBoxCarEngSize.Text);
            float carprice = float.Parse(textBoxCARPrice.Text);
            float carTaxcost = float.Parse(textBoxCArTax.Text);

            carReg = Regex.Replace(textBox1CARregplate.Text, " ", "").ToUpper();
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO stockList (Manufacturer,CarModel,BodyColour,AquiredMileage,RegistartionYear,CarRegistration,FuelType,EngineSize,Price,CarTaxCost12Months) VALUES (@Manufacturer, @carModel, @carColour, @carMileage, @carYearReg, @carReg, @fuel, @carEng, @carPrice, @carTaxCost)";

                cmd = SDS1.Prepare(cmd);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manufacturer", carManufacture);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carModel" , carModel);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carColour" , carColour);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carMileage" , carMileage);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carYearReg" , carYearReg);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carReg" , carReg);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fuel" , fuel);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carEng" , carEng);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carPrice" , carprice);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carTaxCost", carTaxcost);


                SDS1.Query(cmd);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex);
            }



        }
```

Comment: You should create a [**`UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024.aspx) on that field (assuming you are using MS SQL Server)

Comment: Create a unique constraint on that field in the database. An exception will be thrown.

Comment: The REGISTRATION NUMBER is a primary key, this will be unique, When you enter a duplicate, it prints in the console that an sql error has occured, so it does see duplicates. But i want the error in a form of a message box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you first make sure that no two identical car registration are in the database.

I assume, a car registration is a unique key in your scenario. You can create a `unique key` constraint on your table. As this is probably your defining column in your table, you should create a so-called `primary key` on your car registration column:

```
ALTER TABLE stockList
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_stockList_CarRegistration PRIMARY KEY (CarRegistration)
```

Now, if you insert the same key for a second time, the database will throw an exception.

You need to catch this exception and tell the user nicely what he did wrong.

If you want a comfortable UI, you might want to load all existing car registrations from the database and tell him that this one alredy exists before the user types in all the other fields.

Comment: This is what im trying to do, on the console output it says that a duplicate is found. How can i get this to be shown on the app that im doing

Comment: The `Console.WriteLine` is your own code, you can change it to whatever you want. `MessageBox.Show` for example if you are using `Windows Forms`.

Comment: Well im using a WPF Application which is writen in C#, Using the MessageBox.show doesnt bring anything up at all.

Comment: If you don't see the `MessageBox`, but you *do* see the `Console.WriteLine` then it's not a problem with the database or unique constraints. You might want to open up a separate question concerning your MessageBox problems.

Comment: i dont see the console output either, all i get is an SQL error stating that a duplicate entry has been found

Comment: 22 hours ago you said you got console output. Now you only "get" an error. You might want to sharpen your basic debugging skills. Where do you get it and when do you get it? Do you have updated code?

Comment: Ok when i add a duplicate error, i should get an output on the output window of visual studio (The output box on the bottom). The error SHOULD be like this:

ERROR: BLAHBLAHBLAH about a duplicate found.

But in actual result i don't get the word Error: only just the exception. Why doesn't it print the word error out.

If i changed this to a message box a message box wont open.